# Как правильно сформировать запрос на сервер

Tags: java, android, http, httpclient

Веб сайт общается с сервером по примеру:

```
    Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /cost_calc.php HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /cost_calc.php HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [POST /cost_calc.php HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: POST
        Request URI: /cost_calc.php
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: example.com\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0\r\n
    Accept: */*\r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n
    Referer: http://example.com/\r\n
    Content-Length: 1266\r\n
        [Content length: 1266]
    Cookie: _ga=GA1.3.187715172.1481965656; _gat_UA-76707418-1=1\r\n
        Cookie pair: _ga=GA1.3.187715172.1481965656
        Cookie pair: _gat_UA-76707418-1=1
    DNT: 1\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://example.com/cost_calc.php]
    [HTTP request 1/4]
    [Response in frame: 8]
    [Next request in frame: 11]
    File Data: 1266 bytes
HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Form item: "data" = "{"user_full_name":"андрей","user_phone":"(111)111-11-11","client_sub_card":null,"required_time":null,"reservation":false,"route_address_entrance_from":"","comment":"привет","add_cost":0,"wagon":false,"minib
        Key: data
        Value [truncated]: {"user_full_name":"\320\260\320\275\320\264\321\200\320\265\320\271","user_phone":"(111)111-11-11","client_sub_card":null,"required_time":null,"reservation":false,"route_address_entrance_from":"","comment":"\320\277\321\
    Form item: "url" = "http://194.183.173.18:7200/api/weborders/cost"
        Key: url
        Value: http://194.183.173.18:7200/api/weborders/cost




Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 200
        Response Phrase: OK
    Server: nginx/1.10.2\r\n
    Date: Mon, 02 Jan 2017 12:13:54 GMT\r\n
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    Vary: Accept-Encoding\r\n
    Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n
    \r\n
    [HTTP response 1/4]
    [Time since request: 0.306525000 seconds]
    [Request in frame: 5]
    [Next request in frame: 11]
    [Next response in frame: 14]
    HTTP chunked response
        Data chunk (144 octets)
            Chunk size: 144 octets
            Data (144 bytes)

0000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 2d cd 4d 0a c2 30   ..........-.M..0
0010  10 40 e1 ab c8 ac 45 48 53 4b d3 cb 84 c9 64 a2   .@....EHSK....d.
0020  01 49 42 7e 16 a5 08 de c9 b5 77 a8 37 32 a2 db   .IB~......w.72..
0030  8f 07 6f 03 eb 4b c2 4a 57 1f 2e 3a 66 cb 59 37   ..o..K.JW..:f.Y7
0040  6f 61 01 69 78 98 49 8c c6 4c 34 4e 42 ce 52 91   oa.ix.I..L4NB.R.
0050  38 1b 87 03 3a 29 15 c3 11 7e 39 c5 52 bf bd 50   8...:)...~9.R..P
0060  9d a8 e5 cc 81 d6 0e 87 fd f9 7e ec af 53 d7 fe   ..........~..S..
0070  a0 d8 42 d5 35 fb 04 8b c3 5b e1 de 62 d0 09 57   ..B.5....[..b..W
0080  6d 62 68 85 cb df ef 1f d3 04 5e 0d 93 00 00 00   mbh.......^.....
                Data: 1f8b08000000000000032dcd4d0ac2301040e1abc8ac4548...
                [Length: 144]
            Chunk boundary: 0d0a
        End of chunked encoding
            Chunk size: 0 octets
        \r\n
    Content-encoded entity body (gzip): 144 bytes -> 147 bytes
    File Data: 147 bytes
Line-based text data: text/html
    {"dispatching_order_uid":"3be28c14bb6c4613839c15bfa2af339e","order_cost":"319","currency":" \320\263\321\200\320\275.","discount_trip":false,"can_pay_bonuses":false}
```

---

Как сымитировать это общение с помощью приложения для Android?

Я пробую отправить запрос в виде:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(host + app);
        String toSend = "HTML Form URL Encoded: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n" +
                //"    Form item: \"data\" = \""+params[0]+"\"\n" +
                "    Form item: \"data\" = \"{\"user_full_name\":\"Andrew\",\"user_phone\":\"(111)111-11-11\",\"client_sub_card\":null,\"required_time\":null,\"reservation\":false,\"route_address_entrance_from\":\"\",\"comment\":\"\",\"add_cost\":0,\"wagon\":false,\"minibus\":false,\"premium\":false,\"flexible_tariff_name\":\"Базовый\",\"baggage\":false,\"animal\":false,\"conditioner\":false,\"courier_delivery\":false,\"route_undefined\":false,\"terminal\":false,\"receipt\":false,\"route\":[{\"name\":\"ДАВЫДОВА АЛЕКСЕЯ БУЛЬВ.\",\"number\":\"3\"},{\"name\":\"ЦУЛУКИДЗЕ УЛ.\",\"number\":\"12\"}],\"taxiColumnId\":0,\"app_registration_token\":\"\",\"pay_bonuses\":0}\n" +
                "    Form item: \"url\" = \"http://194.183.173.18:7200/api/weborders/cost\"";
        try {
            toSend= URLEncoder.encode(toSend, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept","*/*");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        httppost.setHeader("Cookie", "_ga=GA1.3.187715172.1481965656");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httppost.setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httppost.setHeader("DNT", "1");
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(toSend));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, responseStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseStr;
```

и получаю в ответ просто OK без данных.

Comment: опишите какой запрос вы хотите сделать на сервер. судя по коду вы не правильно передаете данные. для андроида есть хорошая библиотека [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). попробуйте ее.

Comment: `toSend` выглядит довольно безумно. Вы уверены, что данные нужно посылать именно в таком формате?

Comment: @Alexey Ten если был уверен, то не писал бы сюда. Это уже n-ая попытка.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman спасибо за библиотеку. Правильный запрос-ответ есть в дампе. Я уже много вариантов перепробовал.

Comment: дамп надо вставить в сообщение

Comment: Что на сервере? Откуда мы знаем, что в ответе должны быть какие-либо данные?

Comment: Там ещё и Basic авторизация

Comment: @MikhailVaysman дамп большой потмоу залил его на файлообменник. Ссылка есть в вопросе.

Comment: @vp_arth 
>Что на сервере? Откуда мы знаем, что в ответе должны быть какие-либо данные?
Потму что они есть в дампе общения страницы с сервером.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным, без скачивания подозрительных файлов с сомнительных файлообменников. Почитайте: [mcve]